# Access Postgres running on Mac OS X from Windows 10 (Parallels) dbForge Studio

Tags: macos, postgresql, windows-10, dbforge

I am currently developing a **Golang** app and I am using PostgreSQL. The thing is, I found **[dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/studio/)** which I would like to try. However, for some reasons, I am not able to connect to my database, I don't understand why.

I created a "ServerTest" with *Postgres.App* (on Mac OS), running on `localhost:5432`. It has 3 database:

- emixam23
- postgres
- template1

From *dbForge Studio Express*, I tried to open a connection:

- **Host:** 127.0.0.1
- **Post:** 5432
- **User:** root
- **Password:** root
- *Allow saving password checked*
- **Database:**

`Connection Name: 127.0.0.1`

It fails : `Error: 08006: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5432 CONNECTION FAILURE`

However, after some researches on internet, it seems that it's a bit different than localhost since it's a virtual machine windows, so I tried from my rooter address:

**10.211.55.2**

But still, it doesn't work, same error. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Depending on your version of PostgreSQL and your setup, you may need to change your port. The default port for versions <10 is 5432, for version 10 it is 5433.

Comment: Hey thanks, I now get `Timeout Expired`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide any advice beyond what I've given (I've never used Golang or dbForge), I just thought it was important to note as it's a definite "gotcha" in the PgSQL space.

Comment: Alright thanks for trying to help anyway :)

Comment: @e_i_pi default port for 10 is still 5432. if you have 5433, it must be upgrade script or smth...

Comment: @Emixam23 connect to your `ServerTest` and run `show hba_file` then open the resulting file and change reject to md5 against local authentication

Comment: Argh, right you are @VaoTsun. I have two installations of PgSQL, so the second one has defaulted to 5433 doh!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the answer is coming to late for you here, but hopefully this will be accepted as the answer to assist people in the future.

*Paths could change based on installation method, this assumes Postgress.app*

Default path here will be referred to as path, for ease o: /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Postgress/var-[version]

1. Setup a PGDATA environment variable pointed to the path of the application, you can set this up in your shell profile script, but we will just run this from the command line. Replace [username] with your OSX username and the  with your version. As of this writing that would be 11:

`export PGDATA="/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-[version]`

example, user LimpingNinja, version 11:

`export PGDATA="/Users/LimpingNinja/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-11`

2. Modify $PGDATA/postgresql.conf and add the following to the end of the file and save it (if you already have this defined, modify it as needed):

`listen_addresses = '*'`

3. On your Parallels virtual machine open up a CMD Prompt and type 'ipconfig'. This will output some data, you should look for the line that says "Default Gateway" it may have an ipv6 address (which may appear as gibberish) but the address you are looking at looks like below:

`Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.1`

4. Modify $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf and add the following line, replace the 10.211.55.1 with whatever you had in Step 3. I used a /32 at the end of mine (just in case the address changes) but you could likely use a /4 or /8 if you wanted to constrain this more:

`host all all 10.211.55.1/32 md5`

5. Open up Parallels and go to Menu Preferences -> Network and make sure you are in 'Shared' in the left pane. On the right pane check the box for "Show in System Preferences". You may have to click the Lock Icon if this is grayed out. Close when done.
6. Open System Preferences -> Network and click on Parallels Shared Network (or similar) and note down the IP Address, default is usually 10.211.55.2
7. Inside of your Parallels Windows VM, edit the hosts file which appears at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the line below, replacing the IP address (10.211.55.2) with whatever you had from Step 6. **Note: You might not be able to save directly here, so copy that file to somewhere you have access, edit it, and then copy it back overwriting the original for ease**

`10.211.55.2 vmhost`

8. In OS X, restart Postgres. When using Postgres.app simply open it up and click [Stop] followed by [Start]
9. Within your Parallels Windows VM you should now be able to connect to vmhost:5432 with PGAdmin, Connection String, or whatever.

This was sourhttps://gist.github.com/justingarrick/11180527

Comment: Hey :) Yeah I am not on PostGres anymore, but let see how people upvote your question :) Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

It looks like connectivity configuration problem.
Try to connect with native tools e.g pgAdmin. In case of successful connection it proves dbForge problem. Otherwise try to find an answer in Pg configuration, or in network availability of your virtual machine.